# How to convert UInt8 to bytes Swift 4

Tags: swift, ascii

How do I convert 4 to 0x04 in Swift 4?

```
var value: UInt8 = 4 // want to input 4
let bytes = NSData(bytes: &value, length: sizeof(UInt8())) // bytes must = 0x04
```

Answer (score 0):

If "bytes must = 0x04" it sounds like you want a `Data` with a single byte with a value of `4`, right? The code you have written will produce an `NSData` with an array of bytes that represents the memory address of `value`.

If you just want a single byte in your data, you can say `Data(bytes: [value])`.

Comment: Swift 3 or later data conforms to RandomAccessCollection protocol. You can simply say  `Data([value])`

Comment: I need to pass a value to a bluetooth peripheral. The value type is a byte, the value needs to be 0x04.